# Snaps are broken, and I can't work out how to fix

Tags: snap

Today I tried to use intellij-idea for the first time for a few weeks. It tells me that there are updates in snap. There was also a compile error (but this may or may not have been my error).

I have tried to update, but no luck. Here is what I have tried.

```
#↳ sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.

#↳ snap list
Name                     Version   Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core                               9993  latest    canonical✓  broken
core18                             1885  latest    canonical✓  broken
gtk-common-themes                  1506  latest    canonical✓  broken
intellij-idea-community  2020.2.3  257   latest    jetbrains✓  classic
kotlin                             53    latest    jetbrains✓  broken

#↳ snap list --all
Name                     Version   Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core                               9993  latest    canonical✓  broken
core                               9804  latest    canonical✓  disabled,broken
core18                             1885  latest    canonical✓  broken
gtk-common-themes                  1506  latest    canonical✓  broken
intellij-idea-community            249   latest    jetbrains✓  disabled,broken
intellij-idea-community            252   latest    jetbrains✓  disabled,broken
intellij-idea-community  2020.2.3  257   latest    jetbrains✓  classic
kotlin                             50    latest    jetbrains✓  disabled,broken
kotlin                             53    latest    jetbrains✓  broken
```

As you can see snap is telling be that it is broken. What is broken? Did it update to broken code? Why will it not update, when intellij-idea is telling be that there is an update?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the problematic snaps?  Why do you need multiple versions of the same software?

Comment: multiple versions: I was wondering that as well. Snap installed them. I removed the snaps and installed. It seems to have worked. But I don't know why, this worked, and the refresh did not.

Comment: Please consider posting your solution below to help future visitors

Comment: Same here. Update Ubuntu 20.10 with some updates a few days ago, and now my snap apps won't start. I'll try use apt-get instead next time.

Answer (score 4):

## What I did to fix it.

I still have no idea what is wrong with `snap`, but this work around worked for me.

### Remove all packages

```
for package_name in …
do
    sudo snap remove $package_name
done
```

### Re-install packages

```
for package_name in …
do
    sudo snap install $package_name
done
```

Replace the ellipses as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes snaps fail to mount. `systemctl --failed` shows failed ones. Need to start them via `systemctl start <...>` then reconnect the failed snap packages via `snap disable <pkg>` then `snap enable <pkg>`. `snap revert <pkg>`/`snap refresh <pkg>` also fix failed snap packages. Reinstall works for sure, but there is a shorter way.

Here is the script to fix that:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

alwaysfix=chromium
[ -z "$1" ] || alwaysfix="$1"

tofix="`snap list | awk '/broken/{print $1}'`"

for t in `COLUMNS=1000 systemctl --failed | awk '/snap.+mount/{print $1}'`; do
        systemctl start "$t"
done

for s in $tofix; do
        snap disable "$s"
        snap enable "$s"
done

for s in $alwaysfix; do
        snap disable "$s"
        snap enable "$s"
done
```

Comment: Hi Roman, I am not familiar with linux. I have win10+wsl2+ubuntu20.04. After windows reboot, snap all broken including core. Running your script, I got error "core" (11167) security profiles (cannot find installed snap "core" at revision 11167: missing file /snap/core/11167/meta/snap.yaml". Could you please take another look for me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: this method didn't work for me. I had to remove and reinstall each package.